# XSLT output is duplicated version 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml I am trying to sort and output to an HTML table.

```
<Fleet>
<Engine>
  <Parts>
    <Part cii="AF">
       <Part cii="DF8">
          <Part cii="PF1"/>
          <Part cii="PF2"/>
       </Part>
       <Part cii="DF3">
          <Part cii="PF4"/>
          <Part cii="DF6">
            <Part cii="LF10"/>
            <Part cii="EF11" />
          </Part>
       </Part>
    </Part>
  </Parts>
</Engine>
</Fleet>
```

and using the XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <xsl:text>CII</xsl:text>
    </td>
   </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Part">
         <xsl:sort select="@cii" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Part">
    <tr>
       <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="@cii" />             
       </td>
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Part">
            <xsl:sort select="@cii" order="ascending"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each> 
   </tr>    
</xsl:template>
```

I'm able to sort the output by cii like I intend to.  Child parts are nested within their parents and sorted as I expect. However, except everything below the master parent part (ie CII="AF") is duplicated one time as a block in the output. I've omitted the html.  Is this a grouping issue or something with the for-each I'm using?

```
<Fleet>
<Engine>
  <Parts>
    <Part cii="AF"> <!--All Parts below this get repeat in same order as a block-->
       <Part cii="DF3"> 
          <Part cii="DF6">
            <Part cii="LF10"/>
            <Part cii="EF11" />
          </Part>
          <Part cii="PF4"/>
       </Part>
       <Part cii="DF8">
          <Part cii="PF1"/>
          <Part cii="PF2"/>
       </Part>
       <Part cii="DF3"...> <!- repetition of the block above starts->
    </Part>
  </Parts>
</Engine>
</Fleet>
```

expected output - now in the right place

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>CII</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>AF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>DF3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>DF6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>EF11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>LF10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>PF4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>DF8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>PF1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>PF2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you want to preserve the original nesting structure, start with one level instead of all `Part`s, i.e. change `<xsl:apply-templates select="//Part">` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="Fleet/Engine/Part"/>`. If you want to flatten the original structure then use `<xsl:apply-templates select="//Part">` but using recursion in addition later down with `<xsl:apply-templates select="Part">` can only give you duplicates. You haven't shown us the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Martin  Fleet/Engine/Parts/Part got me what I needed.